# stuck with dstack and dsplit in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I understood hstack , hsplit and vstack and vsplit 
But I didn't get how dstack and dsplit are working.

According to me concatenating on 3rd dimension shoud mean something like:>

```
a = 1st 2D matrix
b = 2nd 2D matrix
c = 3rd 2D matrix

d = np.dstack((a, b, c))

d[0] == a
d[1] == b
d[2] == c
```

Now this should really mean depth stacking and really make sense (at least to me)
But this is not the case.
Please help me visualize dstack and dsplit

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are thinking about it the right way. I.e. imagining the arrays being vertically stacked...

Like the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) say:

> Take a sequence of arrays and stack them vertically to make a single
>   array

Imagine that a,b and c are square and stack to form a cube. Looking at the first dimension, `d[0]` (equivalent to `d[0,:,:]`) will look at the side of the cube, as will `d[:,0,:]`. The third dimension looks from above, e.g. `d[:,:,0]`. It helps to use `.ndim` and `.shape` to work out the number of dimensions and shape.

To illustrate:

```
>>> a =np.ones((3,3))
>>> b =a*2
>>> c =a*3
>>> np.dstack((a, b, c))
>>> a.shape
(3, 3)
>>> a.ndim
2
>>> d.shape
(3, 3, 3)
>>> d.ndim
3
>>> d[0,:,:]
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
>>> d[:,0,:]
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
>>> d[:,:,0]
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> d[:,:,1]
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Finally, you could always transpose the array if you wanted to 'rotate the cube':

```
>>> d.T
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.]]])

>>> d.T[0]
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

**EDIT**

.... or you could use [`rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis):

```
>>> np.rollaxis(d,2)
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.]]])
```

Comment: This gave me one use of dstack ...not dstack actually but dstack().T....but I am really curious as to why numpy guys made dstack (obviously not only for getting its transpose and using it) . There must be some use behind it.

Comment: and this method (getting dstack's transpose and then getting individual elements) is  not valid for higher dimensions

Answer (score 1):

`dstack((a,b,c))` is the same as `dstack(map(atleast_3d, [a,b,c]))` so if you only need to understand how `atleast_3d` works. That's simple, it just adds a third dimension of size 1:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(2, 3)
>>> np.atleast_3d(a)
array([[[ -1.47499777e-04],
        [ -3.15172826e-01],
        [ -4.17205640e-01]],

       [[ -4.40166377e-01],
        [ -3.49488016e-01],
        [  1.20570170e+00]]])
```